Best way to find the meshing with lowest number of elements allowing a max error of 1%?
So, I have a reference simulation meshing that's 100% reliable but it's costly in terms of time so I'm looking for optimizing it by finding the minimum mesh allowing at most 1% of error with respect to that reference meshing. What's the best "algorithm" I can do? It's 2D so I thought of doubling number of elements in both directions if error > 1% after initialization with a random meshing, and if error < 1%, I lower both by 1/4. If it's <1%, I lower again, if >1%, I choose the average between it and the previous one.
Is there any more efficient technique?

How do you evaluate your error?

Absolute value gap between a quantity of a random meshing and a reliable highly-meshed configuration divided by this latter

If you already solved the problem to better than 1% accuracy, why would you want to solve it again on a coarser mesh?

To see if I can solve it keeping the 1% accuracy but with less CPU computation time
